# Gatling Expert needed, script is not performing but i'm getting success

Tags: scala, sbt, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I have a problem with my script It is not performing what is needed however I am getting status Success!

it is not logging in, i recorded the actions using the gatling recorder and did some updates, i tried to clear cache but still not working.

```
  class OP extends Simulation {

  private val baseUrl = "https://url"
  val csvFile = "data.csv"
    //val rampDuration = java.lang.Long.getLong("rampDuration", 0L) // 

  val data: SourceFeederBuilder[String] = csv(csvFile).circular // queue, shuffle, random, circular

  val httpProtocol: HttpProtocolBuilder = http
      .baseUrl(baseUrl)
      .inferHtmlResources()
      .acceptHeader("*/*")
      .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
      .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
      .disableWarmUp
      .disableCaching
      .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0")



  val headers_0 = Map(
      "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")

  val headers_3 = Map("X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest")

  val scn = scenario("Scenario")
      .feed(data)
    })
      .exec(http("request_0")
        .get("/")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .resources(http("request_1")
          .get("/assets/themes/custom/images/usualButtons.png")
          .check(status.is(200)),
          http("request_2")
            .get("/favicon.ico")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .check(status.is(200))))
    .pause(5)
    .exec(http("request_3")
      .post("/userlogin/index/login")
      .headers(headers_0)
      .formParam("login", "username")
      .formParam("password", "pass")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(regex("Keyword").find(1).exists))
    .pause(1)
    .exec(http("request_4")
      .get("/url1")
      .headers(headers_0))
    .pause(2)
    .exec(http("request_5")
      .post("/url1/url2")
      .headers(headers_0)
      .formParam("code_type", "UID")
      .formParam("code", "${data1}")
      .resources(http("request_6")
        .post("/url3")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .formParam("p_id", "${data2}")
        .formParam("p_item_id", "${data3}")))
    .pause(2)
    .exec(http("request_7")
      .get("/url4?value=${data4}")
      .headers(headers_0)
      .resources(http("request_8")
        .post("/url5/${data2}")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .formParam("p_id", "${data2}")
        .formParam("pIds[]", "${data3}"),
        http("request_9")
          .post("/url6")
          .headers(headers_0)
          .formParam("pnum", "${data4}"),
        http("request_10")
          .get("/url7?id=${data5}")
          .headers(headers_0),
        http("request_11")
          .post("/url8")
          .headers(headers_0)
          .formParam("id", "12")))
    .pause(3)
    .exec(http("request_12")
      .post("/url9")
      .headers(headers_0)
      .formParam("id", "${data5}")
      .formParam("p_id", "12")
      .formParam("weight", "500.00")
      .formParam("volume", "0.01")
      .formParam("volumetric_weight", "0.01")
      .formParam("expressMode", "1"))
    .pause(10)
    .exec(http("request_13")
      .get("/")
      .headers(headers_0))
    .pause(1)
    .exec(http("request_14")
      .get("/url/logout")
      .headers(headers_0))
      .exec(flushSessionCookies)
    .exec(flushHttpCache)
    .exec { session => println(session); session }

  setUp(scn.inject(
    constantUsersPerSec(1) during(1 second)
  ).protocols(httpProtocol))
}
```

Could anyone check please and tell me where is the problem with the script.

Comment: First, there is an unexpected `})` in third line of `scn` but I'm assuming that you made a typo while writing this post since it won't compile other way. Beside that there is nothing wrong with this scenario. Please specify what is not working as you expected (and what you expects it to do).

One more thing comes to my mind, how logging is working? You send login and password in POST request and then do nothing with response.

Comment: i'm sending requests for UID and after all these steps, the uid status should be changed, but i think the script is not logging in! after login i should be on the home page to start my test, what should i do with the response?

Comment: It is not a Selenium test, it never is on any page. It only sends requests to server so if you send login request then you should get response which contains either some cookie (gatling should handle it automatically) or some authorization token which should be passed in next requests headers. So it depends on how authorization is implemented in your app.

Comment: Often web sites return a success code when they have done what their authors believe is correct. A login request that detects a login failure and returns a suitable error message can be regarded as a successful request because the web server knew exactly how to handle that request. A web test accessing that login page needs to check whether the response contains text indicating whether the login succeeded or failed. Please [edit] the question to explain what is happening and what is is wanted. The question only states *"it is not logging in"* and that is not enough to understand the problem.